# Can't write Haskell function with the dot operator

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a simple function to convert an `Integer` to a list of its individual digits:

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits 0 = [0]
toDigits n = [toInteger (digitToInt (show n !! x)) | x <- [0..(length (show n) - 1)]]
```

I wanted to chain the

`toInteger (digitToInt (show n !! x))`

with the dot operator like so:

```
toInteger . digitToInt . show . (!!) n x
```

but I think I'm having a misunderstanding of how to compose these functions with the dot operator as this produces illegible (to my haskell-brain) type errors

Comment: why not stick with more readable point-version? I sometimes don't understand the obsession with point-free

Comment: I've incorporated that into my answer, as it's a good point to emphasize. I like trying to see how far the point-free style can be taken, if only to get a better feel for when it stops being more readable that what you are trying to replace.

Answer (score 5):

Point-free style starts to get messy when multi-argument functions are involved. Arguably, something like

```
(toInteger . digitToInt) $ show n !! x
```

is more readable. Read on for some examples progressing towards a point-free version of this expression.

---

First, `show n !! x` is actually `(!!) (show n) x` (because function application has higher precedence that `(!!)`), so you can't directly compose `show` and `(!!)`. Instead, you can write

```
toInteger (digitToInt ((!!) (show n) x))
```

---

Function application also has higher precedence than composition, so you need to use parentheses:

```
(toInteger . digitToInt . (!!)) (show n) x
```

or the `($)` operator, which has lower precedence than composition:

```
toInteger . digitToInt . (!!) $ (show n) x
```

---

Going a little crazy, you could use `flip` to partially apply `(!!)` to `x` first, letting you write

```
toInteger . digitToInt . (flip (!!)) x . show $ n
```

---

Going a little *more* crazy, use `Control.Arrow` and `uncurry` to define a completely point-free function that you can apply to the *pair* `(n, x)`

```
toInteger . digitToInt . (first show >>> uncurry (!!)) $ (n, x)
```

Here, `first show` is a function that takes a pair `(n, x)` and returns `((show n), x)`. This pair is then fed to `uncurry (!!)`; `uncurry` simply creates a function that takes a pair as input instead of two arguments:

```
> :t (!!)
[a] -> Int -> a
> :t uncurry (!!)
([c], Int) -> c
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better invest the time to have a better function, for example

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits = map (read . (:[])) . show

> toDigits 123
[1,2,3]
> toDigits 0
[0]
```

**Explanation**

> `show` converts the Integer into a String, `(:[])` converts each
>   a char into a String, `read` converts the String back to an
>   Integer, those two functions mapped to the elements of the String
>   representation of the original Integer, so what we get back is the
>   digits of the Integer in a list form.

As in your own solution, in the other answer and the comment below, you can simply it further using digitToInt

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)
toDigits = map digitToInt . show
```

Comment: elegant, but could you expand on what `map (read . (:[])) . show` is doing / how it's composing those functions?

Comment: Why not `digitToInt`? Also, this all seems a rather indirect way to calculate.